# Prolog - Finding the average of the elements in a list

Tags: prolog

A little deviant from the usual Prolog-find average, but I have the following code:

```
   % courseAvg
    courseAvg([], 0).
    courseAvg([_+_+Mark|Tail], Avg) :-
        courseAvg(Tail, Number),
        Temp is Number + Mark,
        Avg is div(Temp,2).
```

This does not yield the correct average however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right, the problem is that when your list has one element it calls  `courseAvg([], 0)` which returns 0 and it divides `Mark+0` with `2` while it needs to return just `Mark`.

Add an if condition:

```
courseAvg([], 0).
courseAvg([_+_+Mark|Tail], Avg) :-
        courseAvg(Tail, Number),
        ( Number =\= 0 ->
          Temp is Number + Mark,
          Avg is div(Temp,2);
          Avg is Mark ).
```

(or you could have as base case the list with one element returning mark).
Example:

```
?- courseAvg([9,9,9],N).
N = 9.

?- courseAvg([9,9,8],N).
N = 8.
```

As you can see above it returns only integer number because you use `div/2`. If you want the avg to be floating point replace: `div(Temp,2)` with `/(Temp,2)`:

```
?- courseAvg([9,9,8],N).
N = 8.75.

?- courseAvg([9,8,8],N).
N = 8.5.

?- courseAvg([9,7,8],N).
N = 8.25.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer worked wonderfully. I'll just make a note that I used some wildcards to fit my data structure (i.e. courseAvg([_+_+Mark|Tail], Avg) :-) but this does not affect the overall logic.

Comment: Glad to help!!, yes I noticed the structure and I removed in order to test I will add it back to the code...

Answer (score 1):

An empty list doesn't really have an average since the computation would be undefined (it would be 0/0, since there are 0 elements). I would make the base case be a single element, which is the smallest list that has an average, and let the recursive case deal with at least 2 elements:

```
courseAvg([_+_+Mark], Mark).
courseAvg([_+_+Mark, Next|Tail], Avg) :-
    courseAvg([Next|Tail], Number),
    Temp is Number + Mark,
    Avg is Temp/2.
```

This avoids the miscalculation of the average of a single element that your current implementation does.